# Test data management

Tags: testing, automation, data-management

I am new to automation testing and started working on Selenium webdriver and Nunit framework.

I have some queries related to test data management, and am looking for the best approach.

1. I have to design some test cases where a user registers for an event, but can only register once. If I want to run the test multiple times or run the test on multiple browsers in parallel, what would be the best approach?
2. I need to search for an event and perform some actions on these. These events would not be available if I run the test case after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the logical flag that makes the users registered and then re-use them.  Just avoid re-using users across more than one browser.

If you are using automation and don't need to explicitly test the negative conditions of failing to re-register, then you build the registration clearing into the script.